# Google Maps delegate not working when come again to ViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps

I'm using Google Maps in my App, When I push from another VC and come again to View Controller then there is no effect on mapview.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:true];
    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:coordinate.latitude  longitude:coordinate.longitude  zoom:15.3];

    mapView_.camera = camera;
}
```

delegate method of Google Mapview not called:

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didChangeCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)position
{
}
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView idleAtCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)position
{
}
```

I have created the Google Maps from the storyboard.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet GMSMapView *mapView_;
```

Comment: Did you add Google Maps key in your AppDelegate? Share the code.

Comment: [GMSServices provideAPIKey:googleplacesApiKey];
    [GMSPlacesClient provideAPIKey:googleplacesApiKey]; added in didfinishlaunching in appdelegate

Comment: What do you want to achieve? and also, what are your coordinates for latitude and longitude.